# Is this assertion by Sartre an existentialist reading Pascal's Pensées?

Tags: theology, sartre, pascal

In his book [*What Is Literature?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Literature%3F), [Sartre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre) says:

> Here, I am thinking of Pascal, who relentlessly repeated that man was an irrational composite of metaphysics and history, his greatness unexplainable
>   if he comes from the alluvium, his misery unexplainable if he is still as God made him; that in order to understand man, one had to go back to the simple basic fact of man's downfall.

Should one consider this as an existentialist reading of [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal)'s [*Pensées*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pens%E9es)?

Comment: I'm really curious what comes immediately before this excerpt :)

Comment: @JosephWeissman You can read that [here](http://books.google.be/books?id=SUTeD7u18lsC&pg=PA322): , but it's not really relevant, it seems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking where the referenced ideas can be found in Pascal's corpus, and offering Pensées as a suggestion?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: to some extent yes; I was asking for an explanation of Sartres comment on Pascal; he's obviously referring to the Catholic metaphysics, and existentialism is another interpretation of this, for example Kierkegaard, who is seen as an early precursor to Existentialism.

Comment: Are you partly asking, then, if Sartre is mistaken about the presence of those ideas in Pascal?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I can't recall why I asked the question, it's four years ago...

Comment: If you don't particularly care, maybe you should delete it.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I didn't say I didn't care, I did care four years ago and I would have been interested in a well-sourced answer then.